# Free Pascal IDE (FP) behaviour is strange in Windows 10

Tags: ide, freepascal

I've been using FP 1.0.12 with FPC 3.0.4 (the built in IDE when you install Free Pascal Compiler for Win32, that blue one), usually it worked fine in my old Windows 7. But recently in my new Windows 10 laptop, when I run a program from within the IDE, the console window behave strangely:

1. when I asked for 3 inputs like "readln(a,b,c);" the console asked me 4 times, with the last one actually is not stored
2. when I combine writing text explanation and input like this:

`write('Please input A ... '); readln(a);
write('Please input B ... '); readln(b);
write('Please input C ... '); readln(c);`

all the texts and inputs are in the same place (they are printed overlapping) in the console run window

Anyone got the solution for these strange behaviours? Thank you

Comment: Just tried it on Win10 too, and I can completely reproduce the problem. I can only advise you to use Lazarus. Just tried the same code in Lazarus and in FP. Works as expected usng Lazarus, but not in the FP-IDE. If run outside the FP IDE, it also works fine. So the problem is the FP IDE.

Comment: Yes Rudy Velthuis, I've tried run the application EXE in Command Prompt, and it's working fine. So the problem lies in FP IDE then, so anyone can find a solution, to make FP IDE works fine like in the old times?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution. I tried all kinds of compatibility settings, e.g. with Windows 8.1 or 7, but to no avail. I really suggest you start using Lazarus. It is much more convenient anyway. Or you use unit Crt in your program. Then all works as expected, even when started in FP. But that can cause other problems, of course.

Answer (score 0):

make the write into writeln
such as:

```
writeln('Please input A ... '); readln(a);
writeln('Please input B ... '); readln(b);
writeln('Please input C ... '); readln(c);
```